# AWS / Django - do I save private user uploaded files to S3 or on my EC2 instance?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, django-media

I have a Django web application which allows users to upload their display picture. Some users can see this display picture but not everyone (not all users) should have access to this picture. With that said, in development, I used to save it locally on my machine. In my settings file, I had

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/myProfile/Documents/thisFolder/uPhotosFolder'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and Django would save all user uploaded display pictures to media rood (the uPhotosFolder) which was located on my machine.

With that said, I deployed (or at least am trying to deploy) the app and when I left my MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in my settings file as

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/myProfile/Documents/thisFolder/uPhotosFolder'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and tried uploading an image, it said access was denied. Apparently I have to go into my EC2 instance (I use Amazon Web Services) and create the

```
'/home/myProfile/Documents/thisFolder/uPhotosFolder'
```

directory and then start saving the display images.

My question is, is this the correct / best way to save private user uploaded images on the server? Or should I use S3 for this as well? (From what I read, images on S3 are stored on the cloud and can be accessed from a URL by anyone) Is there a way to use S3 for my situation right now?

Comment: You might want to look at using django-storages: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The question whether you store the image on EC2 instance in a folder or on S3 Storage is independent of the file privacy.

The MEDIA_ROOT defines the location of Media Folder. The MEDIA_URL defines the URL formed when serving media.

Now for storing if we use default file system storage we end up saving file in MEDIA_ROOT. We can change the storage to S3 by some additional configuration in settings file. ( [Docs Here](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) )

Now securing your files on user basis can be done by restricting access to URLs. For this Media URLs can be protected using X-Accell-Redirect headers use when using nginx to serve files.( eg: [Here](http://glitterbug.in/blog/serving-protected-files-from-nginx-with-django-11/show/) ).
In case you go ahead and use the S3 storage for serving media files ( more preferable in production environment ) - The S3 storage provides functions to get a protected URL for media which can be passed to client to retrieve media. These urls have accessibility for limited time period.